# Connecting actions works. Connecting outlets doesn't

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xib, iboutlet

I have a `XIB` file with my controls in it, loaded in the Interface Builder (Xcode 4.0.2 on Snow Leopard).

The file's owner is set to, let's say, the `someClassController` class, and I've also added (in the Interface Builder) an NSObject instance of `someClass`, as well.

I've managed to link e.g. a button with an action in someClassController or someClass - and it works for both of them.

**However**, whenever I link an outlet to ANY of them, it fails to show up; and `NSLog` reports `NULL` pointers.

- ***Hint :** My issue here could be much more complicated than it seems, since both my someClass and someClassController classes inherit other classes, which inherit other classes and so on (I'm dealing with a huge-to-chaotic codebase, and I don't really know what else could be helpful to post)... However, I would still like to hear your opinion on what might be going wrong in such a case...*

Comment: In what method are you checking for the existence of your outlets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see problems like this, it's almost always because you have more than one object of the kind that has the outlet. The one in the nib whose outlet you connected is not the one that is examining its outlet.

To investigate this, add statements in the object's initializer method(s) and possibly `awakeFromNib` to log the value of `self`.

Some (or all, or none) of the objects may be created in nibs, and some (or all, or none) of them may be created in code; objects in the latter group won't trip `awakeFromNib`, since they didn't.

Either way, once you've inventoried what instances of the class you have, you can kill them off until you're left with the ones you want.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for help. Your approach definitely makes sense. However, I just rechecked and there is just one instance of `someClass` running... (Actually, I made some progress, although I still can't figure out what's going on... How could a NSTextField outlet appear, and not an NSMenu outlet?! Either this is simply weird, or I've spent more time in front of code than i should have had... lol)

Comment: Would you mind have a look at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774862/chromium-tabs-in-cocoa-outlets-turning-up-null-from-tabcontents-xib

Answer (score 1):

To add to Peter Hosey's answer, and after reading some more details in the [other question you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774862/chromium-tabs-in-cocoa-outlets-turning-up-null-from-tabcontents-xib) about this issue, here are some other factors to consider:

1. The File Owner class selected in the nib is completely ignored at runtime. It's there only for design-time convenience – for checking available actions and outlets.
2. Is there any chance you're finding nil pointers in `-init`? Outlets are connected **after `-init`** and **before `-awakeFromNib`**. They'll never be connected in `-init`.

I'm trying to understand the sequence of initialization (from your other post). It sounds like you are creating a new instance of your `CTTabContents` subclass, and passing it to your `CTBrowserWindowController` subclass's `-addTabContents:` method. Then the `CTBrowserWindowController` loads your objects from the nib.

Or, maybe that's wrong. You might be creating a instance of your `CTTabContentsController` subclass. Then that object is loading `TabContents.xib`.

It's important to track down **where the nib is being loaded** and **which object is being provided as the file owner at that time**.

Another question: are you using manual release/retain, automatic reference counting, or garbage collection?

Finally, I reiterate the importance of printing out the `self` pointer in your initialization methods. In addition to `-init` and `-awakeFromNib`, try other initialization methods like your `CTTabContents` subclass' `-initWithFrame:`. When you're discovering intermittent null pointers in the rest of your debugging, print out the `self` pointers then, too. You'll probably be seeing different values of `self` then, too.