# Chromium Tabs in Cocoa (Outlets turning up NULL from 'TabContents.xib')

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, tabs, interface-builder, iboutlet

I'm struggling to use [Chromium Tabs](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=chromium%20tabs%20cocoa&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=https://github.com/rsms/chromium-tabs&ei=XmxnT4fNCoiU8gPE7KC0BQ&usg=AFQjCNElttpKq-kWasmKyvQa6K1cx8R1ug) in Cocoa and I really seem to be missing something.

- I've subclassed `CTBrowserWindowController` (`ppEditor`), `CTBrowser` (`ppDocumentBrowser`), `CTTabContents` (`ppDocument`) and `CTTabContentsController` (`ppDocumentController`)
- Editor creates new Documents by : `[self addTabContents:(ppDocument*)doc];` (and I've also tried first adding a Document Controller for the specific document first, but this doesn't work either)
- I'm connecting my outlets from `TabContents.xib` (either to File Owner : `ppDocumentController` or to an instance of `ppDocument` I'm adding to the XIB), but it **doesn't work** and the outlet instances show up (intermittently) as `NULL` pointers.

So, what could be going wrong?

**NOTE :**

- When connecting actions (either to the ppDocument class, or the ppDocumentController), these - weirdly so - do work....
- *There is some cross-referencing between classes (e.g. there is a pointer to `ppDocument` from `ppDocumentController`, as well as one from `ppDocument` to `ppDocumentController`)*

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764605/connecting-actions-works-connecting-outlets-doesnt isn't it? Would you just add the additional information there instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

Although, I have no idea how - I basically did the whole thing from scratch and ooops, it worked (I must have missed something in the first place...)